# Correct format of event registration

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-mobile

As documented `.live()` is deprecated since jquery 1.7, so i am using `.on()` for my button and page events. But the problem is `.on()` is not working properly in my jquery mobile app.

what is the correct format of `<a href="#">`, `data-role=button`, and button click events
and page events (pageinit, pagebeforeshow) in jquery mobile?

i using am jquery 1.8.2 and jquery mobile 1.2.0 and phonegap 1.5.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What _is not working properly_? The equivalent of `$(<selector>).live("click", ...)` would be `$(<parent element>).on("click", <selector>; ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Use .bind to accomplish this.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/bind/